# How to implement an efficient folder search in a Windows Explorer extension

Tags: winapi, windows-shell, windows-explorer

I'd like to implement a Windows Explorer extension that works like this:

- The extension quietly records all folders the user visits in Windows Explorer.
- A shortcut command like `Ctrl+F3` activates the extension. The user can then type some parts of a folder name or path, and the extension shows the recently visited folders that most closely match the search query. The user can then select a folder, which lets Windows Explorer navigate there.
- An important point: I don't want to just extend the standard Windows Explorer. I need to extend the Open File Dialog as well, i.e. these windows:

[image]

The Open File Dialog is something that runs inside other applications, so the task might be a bit more difficult. However, I'm pretty sure that it is possible. For example, Shell Namespace Extensions or Context Menu items are visible in both the standard Windows Explorer **and** the file dialogs in other applications. That's why I'm pretty sure there must be a way to implement such an extension.

What's the best way to implement it?

**Edit:** By the way, if someone knows of such an extension, I'd be very happy to know.

Comment: I believe you can do all of this without writing a shell extension, which are complicated beasts, often causing problems in other processes (whose devs love to track down *your* bugs - **not**). Instead, just write a separate program that [tracks navigation changes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130613-00/?p=4093/). Call `IShellBrowser::BrowseObject()` to make Explorer or File Dialog navigate to a new folder.

Comment: @zett42 Sounds great, wasn't aware of that option. Would that work in Open File dialogs in other processes?

Comment: I did some quick testing, unfortunately `IShellWindows` enumerates only Explorer windows. You can send the undocumented `WM_GETISHELLBROWSER (WM_USER + 7)` to a file dialog to obtain an `IShellBrowser` pointer, but you would need DLL injection for this (e. g. using a Windows hook), because the pointer is only valid in the other process. You may play around with `AccessibleObjectFromWindow()`, but in my quick test I wasn't successful with that.